# How to convert this sql part to linq

Tags: sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

```
select sum(DATEDIFF(day,LeaveBreakup.StartDate,LeaveBreakup.EndDate)+1)
```

what I want is to convert the statement to linq select statement

Comment: Research the basics of LINQ. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386928%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class LeaveBreakup
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

List<LeaveBreakup> Dates = new List<LeaveBreakup>();
Dates.Add(new LeaveBreakup(){StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3), EndDate = DateTime.Now });
Dates.Add(new LeaveBreakup(){StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), EndDate = DateTime.Now });
```

LINQ BIT

```
var Result = (from D in Dates
                select (D.EndDate - D.StartDate).TotalDays + 1)
            .Sum();
```

If you want to know the diff without having to worry about having a negative value then wrap the calculation in Math.Abs

```
var Result = (from D in Dates
                select Math.Abs((D.StartDate - D.EndDate).TotalDays) + 1)
            .Sum();
```

In this example your Result is 7